# Why does my shell script give the error: "declare: not found"?

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

Here is a simple example showing that using `declare` in a script the script will not run, while sourcing the script will:

```
$ cat /tmp/new
#! /bin/sh
declare -i  hello
$ chmod a+rwx /tmp/new
$ /tmp/new
/tmp/new: 3: declare: not found
$ source /tmp/new
$
```

I wonder why directly running the script doesn't work, while sourcing it does? How can I make the first one work? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`declare` is a builtin function and it's not available with `/bin/sh`, only with `bash` or `zsh` (and maybe other shells). The syntax may differ from one shell to another. You must choose your sheebang (`#!`) accordingly: if the script needs to be run by bash, the first line must be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 9):

`declare` is a bash and zsh extension. On your system, `/bin/sh` is neither bash nor zsh (it's probably ash), so `declare` isn't available. You can use `typeset` instead of `declare`; they're synonyms, but `typeset` also works in ksh. In ash, there's no equivalent to `typeset -i` or most other uses of the `typeset` built-in. You don't actually need `typeset -i` to declare an integer variable; all it does is allow a few syntactic shortcuts like `hello=2+2` for `hello=$((2+2))`.

Answer (score 3):

`declare` probably doesn't exist in the shell defined by your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) - `#! /bin/sh`.

Try `#!/bin/bash` instead.

The reason why sourcing it worked is that you were already in a shell that supports declare. Sourcing it didn't open a new shell thus **didn't use** the shebang that doesn't know declare.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try the 2 other equivalent versions to Bash's `declare`, which are: `typeset` and `local`. They all work with `-i` (for *integer*). Also see my [test script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381416/1147688). PS. `declare` is not yet implemented in the **Android** (Mksh).

Comment: `local` works fine

Comment: typeset will work for ksh