# mapfile: not found

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am getting an error regarding mapfile. mapfile should be installed on the server:

```
(base) mh-ikom01:$ mapfile -h
bash: mapfile: -h: invalid option
mapfile: usage: mapfile [-d delim] [-n count] [-O origin] [-s count] [-t] [-u fd] [-C callback] [-c quantum] [array]
```

head of the script

```
mapfile -s 1 -t files < files.txt
    echo "${files[@]}"
    for FILE in ${files[@]}; do
            prefetch --max-size 300G $FILE
            fastq-dump --split-files  $FILE
```

when running the script:

```
(base) mh-ikom01:~/projects$ sh script.sh 
script.sh: 1: script.sh: mapfile: not found
script.sh: 2: script.sh: Bad substitution
```

Comment: Why are you running a `bash` script with `sh`?  If you want to use `bash` shell features, then use `bash`.

Comment: Very similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17727/why-does-my-shell-script-give-the-error-declare-not-found